# ネストしてる連想配列で複数ある中身を取得する方法

Tags: php

```
$list = array(
    array(
        'id'=>1,
        'name'=>'a',
        'mail'=> array('a1@mail.com','a2@mail.com')
    ),
    array(
        'id'=>2,
        'name'=>'b',
        'mail'=> array('b1@mail.com','b2@mail.com')
    ),
    array(
        'id'=>3,
        'name'=>'c',
        'mail'=> array('c1@mail.com','c2@mail.com')
    ),
    array(
        'id'=>4,
        'name'=>'d',
        'mail'=> array('d1@mail.com','d2@mail.com')
    )
);

echo 'foreach'."\n";
foreach ( $list as $valueA ) {
    foreach ( $valueA as $varKeyB => $varValueB ) {
        echo '<p>';
        echo $varKeyB . ': ' . $varValueB;
        echo '</p>';
    }
}
```

ID:1 名前:a mail1:a1@mail.com mail2:a2@mail.com
ID:2 名前:b mail1:b1@mail.com mail2:b2@mail.com
ID:3 名前:c mail1:c1@mail.com mail2:c2@mail.com
ID:4 名前:d mail1:d1@mail.com mail2:d2@mail.com

上記のように取得したいです

Comment: 前提条件を確認したいのですが、配列の形式はいくつの場合分けが存在しますか？後からこの条件がありましたと言われると回答のしようがありません。すべての場合分けを記述してください。例えばネストは最大N階層までとか、メールは最大n個までとりうるとか、

Comment: 条件はありません。foreach文でid、neme、mailを繰り返して取得できれば大丈夫です

Comment: foreachを２回繰り返している意図は２階層目の配列に不定の配列がくる訳ではないのですね。２階層目のarray以下は必ずid,name,mailが存在してmailが配列で２個値を持っているということですね。

Comment: ええ。もとは下記で行っていたのですが、mail部分の配列の取り方がうまくいかなくて
foreach($list as $key => $value){
    echo 'ID:'.$value['id'].'name:'.$value['name'].$value['mail'].'<br>';
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

おそらくPHPにおける配列でキーの宣言をを省略すると数値添字配列となり、
キーが0から割り当てられることを理解していればそれほど難しい処理ではないでしょう。

参考：[PHP 配列](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/language.types.array.php)

今回の場合

```
$list = array(
    array(
        'id'=>1,
        'name'=>'a',
        'mail'=> array('a1@mail.com','a2@mail.com')
    ),
    array(
        'id'=>2,
        'name'=>'b',
        'mail'=> array('b1@mail.com','b2@mail.com')
    )
);
```

と記述するとキーが宣言されていない配列は数字添字配列となり、内実は

```
$list = array(
    0 => array(
        'id'=>1,
        'name'=>'a',
        'mail'=> array(0 => 'a1@mail.com', 1 => 'a2@mail.com')
    ),
    1 => array(
        'id'=>2,
        'name'=>'b',
        'mail'=> array(0 => 'b1@mail.com', 1 => 'b2@mail.com')
    )
);
```

となります。

ということは

```
echo $value["mail"][0];//mail配列の1番目の要素を取り出す
echo $value["mail"][1];//mail配列の2番目の要素を取り出す
```

という記述の書き方がforeach文の中でかけると思います。
これが理解できれば各配列の取り出し方は理解できると思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。無事解決しました。

Comment: こちらを参考にしてください。「[回答がついたら](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)」ありがとうというコメントは不要です